# Selenium IDE using storeXpathCount with contains in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table that contain the value "ICETS" in the second column. I am using the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeXpathCount</td>
  <td>//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[contains(td[2], "ICETS")]</td>
  <td>Workshop_Count</td>
</tr>
```

However this is giving an error:

`[error] locator not found: name=uocDatatable_length`

Consequently no value for `Workshop_Count` is stored.

The table I am looking at is like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>GHHJG Trees</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>ICETS Shrubs</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>789</td>
  <td>REUT Grass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>120</td>
  <td>ICETS Trees</td>
</tr>
```

I'd expect a value of 2 from my above selenium code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about posting some of the code you are talking about in your answer also in your question? It makes no sense at all in the current combination -> not helpful for anybody...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was my bad, there was a while statement that had not been closed with an endWhile statement. Meaning very strange things were happening. For those who have strange things happen (like storeText not working etc) try these steps:

- Reboot Firefox (sometimes autoupdates make selenium and firefox not play well)
- Reboot machine - my windows 8.1 autoupdates (mandatory in Windows 10?) and this makes windows, firefox and selenium not play well.
- Check for while and endWhile statements that might be missing!